# Can I gaplessly go over to a new Microsoft Office 365 Family 1-year subscription without using the official MS Office subscription renewal?

Tags: office-365

I have bought Microsoft Office 365 Family from a private market place, not from a Microsoft Office site. Now at the end of the one-year subscription, I would prefer buying a one-year subscription again from that private market place.

Will this lead to a gap in the subscription when I change to the new licence? I do not want to have any gap since I fear having to backup my mails and load them newly to a new installation of Outlook, for example. Or what might happen is that I need to reduce my OneDrive size to a size of the free OneDrive for the gap time (which could be minutes or days, it would still make the same problem). I just do not want to backup, re-install or clean anything of my used subscription when I switch over to a new licence.

I do not want to use the renewal of Microsoft Office itself which asks me to do this on their homepage:

> Renew your Microsoft 365 subscription For home. Click below to go to
> the Office renewal page and select the options you want.

The message on Outlook is as follows (translated to English):

> RENEW YOUR SUBSCRIPTION. Please renew within Sunday, 5 December 2021 so that you can continue to use your Office applications without interruption.

In German, here is a message that I get in my Outlook:

[image]

> ERNEUERN SIE IHR ABONNEMENT. Führen Sie bitte innerhalb von Sonntag, 5. Dezember 2021 eine Erneuerung durch, damit Sie Ihre Office-Anwendungen weiterhin ohne Unterbrechung verwenden können.

Buttons after this: `Buy` and `Remind me later`.

But again, I do not want to click on the Buy button or use the MS Office page to prolong the existing subscription, but I want to buy a new subscription and use that as the follow-up subscription without any subscription gaps during the switch.

Can I gaplessly go over to a new Microsoft Office 365 Family 1-year subscription without using the official MS Office subscription renewal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just buy a new Family subscription key from whatever market place, it does not have to be the official Microsoft offer. For a prolonging of an existing subscription, you need to go to

https://redeem.microsoft.com

and enter the 25 number code.

[image]

[image]

The Microsoft store pops up with the MS Office Family package to be opened:

[image]

But do not click on that "Open" button since I guess it will start the Microsoft subscription instead or on top of using your already applied new key.

[image]

Instead, go to your Microsoft account, you will see that your subscription was already prolonged by one year at that moment:

[image]

I prolonged end of November 2021, but the subscription was prolonged 5.12.2021-4.12.2022 nevertheless, so that I do not lose any days of the subscription by prolonging a bit too early:

[image]

Strangely, my Outlook still shows the message to buy a prolonging of the subscription, even after a restart of the computer:

[image]

I guess that this can be ignored since my Microsoft account shows that the license was prolonged by the needed year, just click on "Remind me later" button.

UPDATE much later: yes, do not mind that banner once you have prolonged. It will vanish soon.

[image]